# Spring Framework: what is the purpose of <mvc:annotation-driven />

Tags: spring-mvc

I'm relatively new to Spring and I'm a little confused about the  tag.

After going through the documentation and looking around different posts it seems like the main use of  is that it is required by Spring MVC to dispatch requests to @Controllers.

I created a controller with two requestMappings:

@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value="/health")
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value="/test")

I tested the web app with and without  in the servlet.xml and it doesn't seem like any difference was made with  being omitted or not. The requests seemed to still reach my controller just fine.

Can anyone explain to me what exactly that tag is used for?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The support for `@Controller` and `@RequestMapping` is provided by Spring by default. However, by enabling `mvc:annotation-driven` you get support for processing the requests that are mapped to annotated controller methods, such as declarative validation, formatting and conversion service. An excerpt from [spring's blog](http://spring.io/blog/2009/12/21/mvc-simplifications-in-spring-3-0/) that introduced the new config features

> It applies sensible defaults based on what is present in your
>   classpath. Such defaults include:
>
> - Using the Spring 3 Type ConversionService as a simpler and more    robust alternative to JavaBeans PropertyEditors
> - Support for formatting Number fields with @NumberFormat
> - Support for formatting Date, Calendar, and Joda Time fields with @DateTimeFormat, if Joda Time is on the classpath
> - Support for validating @Controller inputs with @Valid, if a JSR-303 Provider is on the classpath
> - Support for reading and writing XML, if JAXB is on the classpath
> - Support for reading and writing JSON, if Jackson is on the classpath

Another related usefull blog [post](http://thespringthing.blogspot.it/2010/10/what-does-mvcannotation-driven-do.html)

> If this tag is not added to the XML, then you will have to manually
>   define the beans for components like HandlerAdapter, HandlerMapping,
>   Binding Initializer, Request Message converters, etc. This tag helps
>   registering the following components.
>
> - **DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping** - This is a `HandlerMapping`
>     implementation which maps the HTTP requests to the handler methods
>     defined using the `@RequestMapping` annotation.
> - **AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter** - It is responsible for scanning the
>     controllers to identify methods (and parameters) annotated with @MVC
>     annotations. It scans and caches handler methods annotated with
>     `@RequestMapping`. Also handles the `@RequestParam`, `@ModelAttribute`,
>     `@SessionAttributes` and `@InitBinder` annotations.
> - **ConfigurableWebBindingInitializer** - The initializer for the Web Data
>     Binder. Helps in declaratively configuring the Web Binder with
>     validators, conversion services, property editors, etc.
> - **LocalValidatorFactoryBean** - Implements the validator interface and
>     enables JSR303 validation. This is injected into
>     `ConfigurableWebBindingInitializer`.
> - **FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean** - A conversion factory that
>     returns conversion services for basic objects like date and numbers.
>     This factory is again injected into `ConfigurableWebBindingInitializer`.
> - Support for Message Converters

Finally a more formal definition in the official [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-enable)